# Java Scanner requiring me to press enter twice

Tags: java

I am making a very simple game of Battleship to get my head around the concept of OOP.

I have a Board object filled with Square objects, and each Square object keeps track of whether there's a ship(also an object) on it and whether the player has already hit the Square.  My method is supposed to take in coordinates from the player and then update the character on the board ("x" or "o") depending on whether the player hit a ship or not.

It's working fine, except that I have to press enter twice after inputting the coordinates before the program will show me the updated board?  Why is this happening?  How do I prevent the scanner from prompting that additional 'enter' from being pressed?

I have tried to add a String to read the new line after entering the ints (s.nextLine()), but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
public Square[][] userGuess() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your coordinates: x y");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int row = s.nextInt();
        int col = s.nextInt();

        Square target = board[row][col];
        Battleship ship = target.getShip();
        
        target.setUncovered(true);
        
        if(target.isOccupied() == true && ship.getHealth() == 2) {
            ship.setHealth(ship.getHealth()-1);
            System.out.println("Hit!");
        }
        
        else if(target.isOccupied() == true && ship.getHealth() == 1) {
            ship.setHealth(ship.getHealth()-1);
            ship.setAfloat(false);
            System.out.println("You sunk a ship!");
        }
        else if(target.isOccupied() == false) {
            System.out.println("Miss!");
        }
    return board;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting to happen instead. As mentioned, `next*()` methods require unique input prompts (you used it twice, therefore two enters are needed). If you only wanted one, then you need to use it once.

Comment: What do you mean by "*additional 'enter'*"? What are you doing, what you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I know people like to use the Scanner class but using the BufferedReader class is also an option, in fact using the BufferedReader class you do not get that types of occurrences when reading from the user, but obviously it's only my opinion.

Comment: You _shouldn't_ need two enters if you are entering the numbers like "4 5". As long as there is a space there, this should work. And _does_ on my machine. I can't reproduce the bug with the given code. I would recommend placing either a breakpoint or print statement immediately after the second call to nextInt, to verify that that is what is causing you to hit enter twice.

Comment: @B.B The code as posted should behave the way you expect when invoked from an interactive terminal. Can you please use a debugger or print statements to determine where the code stopped after pressing Enter once? It may not be in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Just `String inputString = scanner.nextLine()` and then split the string on a whitespace using `String.split` method and convert the string tokens to ints using `Integer.valueOf`